# In Asp.net MVC Database First, How to get the actual date-range from dropdown field and split to get its first part

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to Select pay period from the drop-down, value of the drop down is date range inserted using nvarchar datatype in database. Now I want to select a date range and then split it at '-' and then use the first part of that date range to do further calculations to auto fill all the fields.

I have tried the code below but as in the drop down it is payperiodId so it is getting the payPeriodId and does not get the actual value of that dropdown field.

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.TimePeriod.PayPeriodId,htmlAttributes: new { @class="control-label col-md-8"})
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.TimePeriod.PayPeriodId,new SelectList(Model.PayPeriods, "PayPeriodId","PayPeriodName"),"Select Payperiod", new {@class="form-control", @id = "StartDate", @onchange = "addDates(), nextDate(),nextDate3(), nextDate4(),nextDate5(),nextDate6(),nextDate7(),nextDate8(),nextDate9(),nextDate10(),nextDate11(),nextDate12(),nextDate13(),nextDate14(),nextDate15()" })

    </div>
<td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DailyRegister.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", @id = "date1" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DailyRegister.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <script>
               
 function addDates() {
                        // split the value in pay period to find start date only and then use that start date to auto insert rest of 14 dates
                        var startdate = document.getElementById("StartDate").value;
                        let arr = startdate.split('-');
                        
                        document.getElementById("date1").value = arr[0];
                       
                    }
                </script>
            </td>
```

This is the code which I am using to calculate further dates - it works fine when i have a date in the field. In this problem i want to read the string and then split its value and use first part to convert into date then use that date for further calculations.

```
<td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DailyRegister.Date2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", @id = "date2" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DailyRegister.Date2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <script>
                function nextDate() {
                    var prev = new Date(document.getElementById("date1").value)
                    //confirm("Previous date is:" + prev);
                    var nextDay = new Date(prev);
                    nextDay.setDate(prev.getDate() + 1);
                    // confirm("next Day is:" + nextDay)
                    document.getElementById("date2").value = nextDay.toDateString();
                }
            </script>
        </td>

public partial class PayPeriod
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public PayPeriod()
        {
            this.TimePeriods = new HashSet<TimePeriod>();
        }
    
        public int PayPeriodId { get; set; }
        public string PayPeriodName { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<TimePeriod> TimePeriods { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: do u mean u just wanna select the date list from a table and put them in a dropdownlist?

Comment: @YatFeiLeong I mean I want to select the date-range from the dropdown list and then split it to get first half of it , to get start date

Comment: like  | 01-01-2022 - 15-01-2022 |  16-01-2022 - 31-01-2022  |  01-02-2022 - 15-02-2022